# How to create an array outside of a function, and be able to add to it in other functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

It seems if I do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then this needs to be in a function, and I can't modify it later using a different function.

I tried just instantiating it in  the .h file,

```
@interface ViewController:
{
  NSMutableArray *Values;
}
```

But then when I try to append to it during runtime, nothing happens. I try to append to it with this:

```
int intRSSI = [RSSI intValue];
NSString* myRSSI = [@(intRSSI) stringValue];
[Values addObject:myRSSI];
```

But the array remains empty when I do this.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you put (randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];) in viewDidLoad function?

Comment: Sorry, did you put (Values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];) in viewDidLoad function?

Comment: FYI - the line in the .h file is a declaration, not an instantiation. Huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to create a property;

```
// ViewController.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *values;

@end
```

Then override the getter for that property, to lazy-initialize it, i.e. the array will be allocated and initialized on first call of the NSMutableArray property's getter:

```
// ViewController.m

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSMutableArray *)values
{
  if (!_values) {
    _values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }

  return _values;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //int intRSSI = [RSSI intValue];
  //NSString *myRSSI = [@(intRSSI) stringValue];
  //[self.values addObject:myRSSI];
  // Keep it simple:
  [self.values addObject:RSSI];
}

@end
```